# maya (mel or python) : can we query the state of the lock selection?

Tags: selection, maya, mel

I would know if - in maya - I can get the state of the 'lock selection'.
I have this command:

```
updateLockSelectionIcon;
```

this command locks and unlock. but there is no argument with. this is a switch which depends on its previous state. But in the script I need to put the lock selection active in first.
by advance thank you.

Comment: This command doesn't appear to do anything if I run it on a sphere. Are you referring to this command? `cmds.lockNode("pSphere1", lock=True)`

Comment: I know this command, it's just an order to avoid to delete the object.

Comment: If it's not related to locking the node then maybe include an image or something, because right now the question isn't clear.

Comment: Hello. I rephrase my question to be more precise.
in fact, I would like that whatever the lock state of the selection, after the execution of the script, the selection is locked.

https://cdnb.artstation.com/p/assets/images/images/024/911/515/large/maxime-neko-lockselection.jpg?1583938088

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe what you're looking for is this:

```
import maya.cmds as cmds

cmds.selectPref(xformNoSelect=True)  # Lock selection.
cmds.selectPref(xformNoSelect=False)  # Unlock selection.
```

And you can also query the lock's state:

```
cmds.selectPref(q=True, xformNoSelect=True)
```

Comment: yes !!! this is exactly what I want ! thank you a lot really.

Comment: If that resolve your answer please accept this answer so others know your issue has been solved.